# sed search for html tags and leave only first and last entry

Tags: html, bash, sed

i use sed to manipulate a html file so that i can import it into wordpress
now i have a problem to unify tags
e.g

```
`<Article> .... <ShortCut>... some text  <ShortCut> some more text ... </ShortCut>
<ShortCut> some more text ... </ShortCut></ShortCut> </Article>...`
```

restult shoul be:

```
`<Article> .... <ShortCut>... some text  some more text ...  some more text ...  </ShortCut> 
</Article>...`
```

is there a way with sed to remove all these ShortCut Tags and leave only the first and the last between the Tags Article?

thx for any help!

**Update:** in the input file there are more then one article. therefore i can only consolidate the ShortCuts per Article section

Comment: Is it all on one line?

Comment: yes all is in one line

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F"</?ShortCut>" '{printf "%s <ShortCut>",$1; for (i=2;i<NF;i++) printf $i;print "</ShortCut> " $NF}' file
<Article> ....  <ShortCut>... some text   some more text ...  some more text ... </ShortCut>  </Article>...
```

Comment: thx for the fast answer! since i have more <Article>..</Article><Article> ..</Article> in one file, how can i limit the search between the start / end of the Article? thx!

Comment: thx for the solution. i have put all the <Articles> in new lineas, so i could use your script. it works perfect. thx!